# Selecting classification model that reflect contributing factors for each outcome class in python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, multilabel-classification

I am working on a multinomial response dataset with multiple categorical predictors.

I chose to run a classification random forest on Python which worked great. I was able to get the most important contributing factors and their partial plots.

I was not able to figure out which predictors contributed the most to which outcome and realized that RF might not be the most appropriate model to understand the dynamic between predictors and multiple outcomes.
I was hoping that you could suggest other models that could reflect the dynamic between outcomes and predictors.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can very well use RF and still get to see how each feature has contributed positively/negatively in making the predictions by using the package `eli5`. I have explained how to leverage the package for doing the same by taking the iris dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from eli5 import show_prediction, show_weights

df = pd.read_csv("./Data/iris.csv")
df.head()

    Sepal   Petal   Width   Height  Class
0   5.1      3.5    1.4      0.2    Iris-setosa
1   4.9      3.0    1.4      0.2    Iris-setosa 
2   4.7      3.2    1.3      0.2    Iris-setosa
3   4.6      3.1    1.5      0.2    Iris-setosa
4   5.0      3.6    1.4      0.2    Iris-setosa

x = df.drop("Class", axis=1)
Y = df["Class"]

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=2,
                       random_state=0)
clf.fit(x,Y)
```

Now lets do the trick using `eli5`. Let's assume that I want to get the contribution of each factor for data point `x.loc[1]`

```
show_prediction(clf, x.loc[1], show_feature_values=True)
```

And this is what you will get

[image: contribution of each factor]

The predicted label for this example is `Iris-setosa` and `width` was the main reason for the prediction to be `Iris-setosa`. Likewise, when you look at the other two columns you will also get an idea as to why the data point is not classified as some other class. If you want a more generic explanation use `show_weights` as shown below

```
show_weights(clf, feature_names = X.columns.values)
```

[image]

`eli5` not only works with RF but a whole bunch of other models as well, please refer to [eli5 documentation](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) for more details.

Comment: I will check it out and get back to you.
One little question tho x.loc[1] is for the outcome for that specific datapoint  or that outcome in general. Can I generalize for my entire dataset or have a full summary? thanks

Comment: Here I have just explained the predictions for just one example, if you would like to have a generic summary I recommend you using `show_weights` instead of `show_prediction`, I have modified the code to show that as well.

Comment: Hi @jaber, if you are happy with my answer, it will be really great if you could accept it as a verified answer and and upvote it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm still exploring it. What does bias mean?